# How to measure Cassandra performance in JMeter

Tags: cassandra, jmeter, database-performance, jmeter-plugins

I want to use JMeter to measure Cassandra response time to some queries and multiple simultaneous accesses.

I'm trying to follow the instructions on this page:

https://github.com/slowenthal/jmeter-cassandra

First, I unpack the archive in the JMeter install directory. However when I try to access the plugin Cassandra through JMeter I can not find it.

Does anyone know if I am follow the appropriate instructions? Or what can I do for everything work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you unpacked the archive into correct location it should be enough to **restart JMeter**
- If you're trying to manually copy jars from cassandra release bundle - the best locations are:

  - for `jmeter-cassandra-x.x.x.jar` - JMeter's /lib/ext folder
  - for all other jars - JMeter's /lib folder
- Third option is to set `user.classpath` property in [user.properties](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) file to point to the folder with the Cassandra jars. Again, JMeter restart will be required to pick the property value up.
- And finally you can use `Add directory or jar to classpath` section of [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan)

[image: Cassandra JMeter]

Latest JMeter 2.13 r1665067 seems to be working fine with jmeter-cassandra-0.9.2